# How to hide a button or link in asp.net Mvc View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have this in my controller action in MVC

```
        if (Profileid == User.Identity.Name)
        {
           ViewBag.Data = true;
        }
```

i want to hide a button or link in my view when this condition is met.how do i go about this in my View. I am using Razor view. thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you simply trying to hide a logon or register button/link based on if a user is authenticated or not?

Comment: @rfmodulator: i am trying to hide a button if user is the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that logic directly in the `View`:

```
@if (Profileid == User.Identity.Name) {

    <input type="submit" ... />

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
If you want based on ViewBag try this:

```
@if(ViewBag.Data == true)
{
//Put code here.
}
```

Or based on ProfileId:

```
@if(ProfileId == User.Identity.Name)
{
//Put code here.
}
```